# Changing labels on a stacked plot

Tags: python, axis-labels, pylot

I have a very simple stacked bar plot.
I have grouped data

```
df=pd.crosstab(pd.cut(df_main['AMOUNT'], 10), df_main['Status'])
df.plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

All I want is to change the tick labels in a range form. Right now label are coming up like `[108742.081, 2206696.838]`, I want them to come up like `108,742` to `2,206,696`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tick labels can be explicitly defined as such:

```
df=pd.crosstab(pd.cut(df_main['AMOUNT'], 10), df_main['Status'])
df.plot.bar(stacked=True, xticks=list_of_X_values, yticks=list_of_Y_values)
```

You can use it with range like this:

```
df=pd.crosstab(pd.cut(df_main['AMOUNT'], 10), df_main['Status'])
df.plot.bar(stacked=True, yticks=list(range(108742, 2206696, 1000)))
```

**Edit:**
If you need to auto define the endpoint you can use this

```
df.plot.bar(stacked=True, yticks=list(range(min(df['y_colname']), max(df['y_colname']), 1000)))
```

Comment: These labels needs to be dynamic, based on amount column and bins made. 
How can I make them dynamic?